# Login session is expired every few seconds

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, flask, flask-login

I use standard Flask-Login library to access my app. Login timeout is 300 min. On my local machine this library works normally - I log in to app, do smth and click "logout" - everything works. 
Then I "push" my app to heroku and log in. I can do something, but after 10-15 seconds session disappears and I have to log in anew.

What's the error?

I tried to resolve the problem, but nothing helps. My heroku plan is "hobby/dev".
If you have any ideas, can you help me?

```
#Init sessions 
Session(app) 
#Login manager 
loginmanager = LoginManager() ... ... 
# Call 'login required' function, when I need to protect my function: 
# View function for custom admin 
@app.route(def_route+'/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
@login_required 
def index(): 
   #try: 
   errorvar = 0 ...`
```

Software that I use:

```
alembic==1.0.7
APScheduler==3.6.0
asn1crypto==0.24.0
Babel==2.6.0
blinker==1.4
certifi==2019.3.9
cffi==1.12.2
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cryptography==2.6.1
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Admin==1.5.3
Flask-BabelEx==0.9.3
Flask-JWT==0.3.2
Flask-JWT-Extended==3.18.0
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-LoginManager==1.1.6
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==2.4.0
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-Script==2.0.6
Flask-Security==3.0.0
Flask-Session==0.3.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.8
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
ndg-httpsclient==0.5.1
passlib==1.7.1
psycopg2==2.7.6.1
pusher==2.1.3
pyasn1==0.4.5
pycparser==2.19
PyJWT==1.4.2
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-editor==1.0.4
pytz==2018.9
requests==2.21.0
six==1.12.0
speaklater==1.3
SQLAlchemy==1.2.18
tzlocal==1.5.1
urllib3==1.24.1
virtualenv==16.2.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
WTForms==2.2.1
```

Set session timelife:

```
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=300)
```

Comment: ..without posting detailed information we can't help you. Start searching in the error-logs and post those? Also mention software versions in your question update. Not in comments.

Comment: Is your session data stored on a database backend? Witch one?

Comment: @daniherrera I don't know where session data is stored. Maybe on hard drive? I just create session (Session(app)), and then use login_required decorator to protect my view. On my local machine everithing works normally, but on heroku doesn't.

Comment: Learn about where session is stored because, on heroku, all memory and all hard disk data is erased on each request.

Comment: @daniherrera I see you. Most likely, that's the problem. Maybe you know, how can I connect flask-login with my PostgreSQL database?

Comment: @ЯригаОлег, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to avoid local `file system` or 
`memory` [SESSION_TYPE](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/), configure one of this services on Heroku:

- redis: RedisSessionInterface
- memcached: MemcachedSessionInterface
- mongodb: MongoDBSessionInterface
- sqlalchemy: SqlAlchemySessionInterface

Heroku's FS and memory is dropped on each request.

Answer (score 1):

You should to try redis for session as dyno clear FS in few scenarios such as once in 24 hours and on every deploy. Using multiple dyno can cause the same issue due to non sharing caching (if FS is used).